# strategy to optimize transferred amounts between accounts to minimize total transferred money？

Tags: python, algorithm

Here are the original records:

| out | in | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| B | C | 6 |
| C | A | 7 |

And I want to minimize the transferred amounts between them. The result I want to get is:

| out | in | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 4 |
| C | A | 1 |

could someone show me how to achieve this?

the purpose is just to minimize the total amount and steps. As you could see, the total amount of first table is 23 and the steps are 3, while the second table only need 2 steps and the total amount is 5.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do in a bit more detail? I can't understand what is your goal and what you are trying to optimise.

Comment: @kostis1101 hi, I just edit my question. It's just try to minimize the transaction steps and the total amount. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Can you share with us what your current code looks like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You want to minimise the total money transferred. As far as I understand, you want to get rid, for example, in the first table of the second transaction between B and C, because it is pointless. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Compute net gain or loss of each account.  Note that this is the only information that you need.  As long as everyone has the correct net gain and loss at the end of the day, you will be happy.  So, you should be able to produce a greedy algorithm that outputs money from net-negative accounts to net-positive accounts.

Comment: Addendum to previous comment: perhaps I spoke too soon.  The problem may not admit a simple greedy algorithm? https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40864/total-flow-using-minimum-number-of-edges-on-a-bipartite-network

Comment: @kostis1101 yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @KevinWang Thanks, I'm trying apply greedy algorithm to it now. And I just found this article helps: https://medium.com/@lloyddanzig/building-a-minimum-transaction-optimizer-in-vba-and-python-8af64c6b0287

Comment: @Joek Yes, I thought a greedy algorithm like the one in that medium post would work.  Unfortunately, upon further examination, it is not guaranteed to work.  However, the worst case of the greedy algorithm is around 2*OPT where OPT refers to the actual optimal number of transactions (whereas not optimizing at all could give you something more like OPT^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshed out answer from my earlier comment:

We can compute the net gain or loss of each account.  Note that this is the only information you need to compute the optimal end result: as long as everyone has the correct net gain and loss at the end of the day, you'll have achieved your desired result.

Then, we can phrase this question as a flow problem on a bipartite graph.  If there are `n` net-positive accounts and `m` net-negative accounts, we can create a complete bipartite flow graph with `m` sources and `n` sinks, each with capacity equal to their desired net flow, and ask the question: what's the minimum number of edges that must have flow across them in order to achieve max-flow?

That seems to be what [this question on Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40864/total-flow-using-minimum-number-of-edges-on-a-bipartite-network) is asking, and it looks like the answer is that the problem is "NP Hard", which roughly means you can't do much better than brute force.

If the numbers you are dealing with are very small, you could also look for a pseudopolynomial-time (which means it's efficient in terms of the size of the AMOUNTS (with your example the amounts are 6,7,1) instead of just the SIZE of the problem (with your example the size of the problem is 3 accounts)) algorithm like the knapsack algorithm.

#### Greedy

The comment you posted shows [a greedy algorithm](https://medium.com/@lloyddanzig/building-a-minimum-transaction-optimizer-in-vba-and-python-8af64c6b0287).  The greedy algorithm fails, for example if the values are

```
1   5 
5   5
5   5
5   5
5   5
5   100
99
```

Optimally, you only need 1 transaction per source account.  However, the greedy algorithm will produce roughly 2 transactions per source account.  In general, the greedy algorithm could produce about twice as many transactions as optimal.

But at worst it will produce something like `n` transactions where `n` is the total number of accounts.  (proof: you will never have a cycle in the graph representing the final transactions, so the maximum number of edges must be `n-1`.)  This is still a big improvement over doing no optimization at all (which can have `O(n^2)` transactions).